# Look up Filter Condition doesn't show record shared by other user

Tags: administration, user-record

I have one account record and it has a field of picklist (Type) and value set to ("salesforce"). This Account Record is created and shared by admin to the roles(x,y,z) by Manual sharing rule.

When i log in with that user(Role x), I have a field with lookup to account. This field have filter condition like "( Account: Type EQUALS Salesforce) ".

When i click the look up of this field , the filter condition is not showing the record which is shared by admin.

Please suggest me the possible way to show the record in lookup window?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Which means the user is already able to see the records. The record has been shared successfully with the user. Yours record sharing rule is working perfect. I think the thing you are looking out is Look Up filter. When the look up field has look up filter criteria, then only those records are shown.